# How to set image of navigation drawer viewer from uri in another activity

Tags: android, image, firebase, picasso

**How I can set image of user which showed in navigation drawer with download URI**

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton buttonSaveImage;
    private FloatingActionButton buttonSelectImage;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 123;
    private Uri filePath;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseStorage fStorage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(filePath).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


        buttonSelectImage = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        buttonSaveImage = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        final View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);




        StorageReference storageRef = fStorage.getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                Log.i("URI VALUE","->"+ uri);
                final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
                Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageViewUser);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        buttonSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonSelectImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Resim Seçiniz"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

                buttonSaveImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        buttonSaveImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                buttonSaveImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (filePath != null) {

                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                    StorageReference storageRef = fStorage.getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    storageRef.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "Fotoğraf başarılı bir şekilde kaydedildi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });


                }
                buttonSelectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use firebase storage to storage images and I do it well, but I can not show that image which I uploaded for user in navigation drawer Image viewer

Navigaiton header

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/overloyBackground"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_user_profile

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="463dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_image_user" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camera"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="250dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="146dp" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/onay"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="299dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="146dp"/>
```

**Here my logcat**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.ytam.fonetegitim, PID: 9482
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ytam.fonetegitim/com.example.ytam.fonetegitim.UserProfileActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.ytam.fonetegitim.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:77)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: It is in question I edit it

Comment: add your xml file here.

Comment: edited in question

Comment: please check my ans.

Comment: share xml layout which include your **NavigationView**

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)' on a null object reference`--> this is `NPE`. Your `navigationView` is null. Make sure it is pointing at correct reference.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: share whole code activity_user_profile.xml

Comment: I added activity_user_profile.xml to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this method I save url to my database storage

```
    private void changeUserPhoto() {

    StorageReference storageRef = fStorage.getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            photoURL = uri.toString();
            Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


        }
    });

}
```

Also with this I use url to make navigation header image

```
private void changePhoto(String myUrl) {

    Picasso.with(this).load(myUrl).transform(new PhotoCircleTransform()).into(profile_image);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this your id is mismatch

**Use this**

```
final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

**Instead of this**

```
final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
```

**EDIT**

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);



    StorageReference storageRef = fStorage.getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            Log.i("URI VALUE","->"+ uri)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageViewUser);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
 cannot be converted to OnNavigationItemSelectedListener get this error on the line View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

**EDIT NEW**

```
final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).(R.id.profile_image);
```

Comment: @YıldırımTAM  what is the issue arriase.

Comment: @YıldırımTAM please check my **EDIT** ans and tell me the log of uri.

Comment: Error:(76, 58) error: incompatible types: UserProfileActivity cannot be converted to OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   get this error on the line   View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

Comment: @YıldırımTAM please check my **EDIT NEW** ans.

Comment: I use your last edit new and there is an error on R.id.profile_image and the error is "Not a statement"

Comment: @YıldırımTAM please add your navigationview xml file here.

Comment: I add it to my question

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


StorageReference storageRef = fStorage.getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

final ImageView imageViewUser =  (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Picasso.with(UserProfileActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageViewUser);

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```